# How can I execute JavaScript in Selenium and grab data?

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, selenium

Hello and thank you for your time.

My purpose is to make parser, that follow the hundreds of sites and check if site has module (special plugin) or not. The main problem, that the only way is to make sure, it a a lunch JavaScript for site.

[image]

So, i don't know how to lunch a javascript and grap data

For example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')    
driver.get("https://lieman.com/")
tag = driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('arsenal_title')")
driver.close()
print(tag)
```

tag prints None.

Can someone helps me to receive data or tell me to other way to check javascipt

===

```
def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
    driver.get("http://redhelper.ru/")
    morn = driver.execute_script("return redhlpSettings()")
    driver.close()
    print(morn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to execute javascript, use [`find_elements_by_class_name(class_name)`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements_by_class_name) or [`find_element_by_class_name(class_name)`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_class_name) instead:

```
tags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('arsenal_title')
```

OR

```
tag = driver.find_element_by_class_name('arsenal_title')
```

---

If you need to use `execute_script` for other reason, and want to get the value of the expression, you need to **return** in javascript side:

```
tags = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('arsenal_title')")
```

---

**UPDATE**

Replace the following line:

```
morn = driver.execute_script("return redhlpSettings()")
```

with:

```
morn = driver.execute_script("return redhlpSettings")
```

because `redhlpSettings` is not a function. You will see an object in javascript is convertd to a dictionary object in python.

Comment: Thank you for you example. But it was like an example.

The real task:

    data = driver.execute_script("return redhlpSettings()") 

and i get error:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: redhlpSettings is not defined.

But as you see console above, it has such method.

Comment: @SergeyBakotin, Then, please provide the code that is reproduce your problem.

Comment: add a real task

Comment: @SergeyBakotin, I think you meant `return redhlpSettings` (without `()`). Even in development console, `redhlpSettings()` throws an exception.

Comment: @falsetry - but with () or without, it has the same error.

Comment: @SergeyBakotin, I've got this as output: `{u'keys': [{u'name': u'\u043b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u043d', u'value': u''}, {u'name': u'\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0434\u0436\u0435\u0440', u'value': u''}], u'chatY': 200}`

Comment: yes, was my syntax mistake. Thank you Comrade, motherland will appreciate your help!